# i want php curl response into object not in string

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I am trying to fetch data from third-party API using curl in PHP. Here it is my code and I want to fetch response in the object. Here I got in string

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, 
  array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
));   

//Ignore SSL certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    

//get response
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//Print error if any
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
echo gettype($output);
```

The response of echo $output is like

```
{"access_token": "", "expires_in": xxxx, "token_type": "", "scope": ""}
```

and another response for echo gettype($output) is print like

```
string
```

but i want into object/array from the curl_response or else i want to convert this string $output into object/array.

Comment: Have a look at the `json_decode` function in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You need to json_decode the response:

```
print_r(json_decode($output));
```